# Insert button is not inserting data into the Database and no errors are given at all

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

This is the class that contains the insert method first I filled the fields and then made properties then the insert method and went to another class and made the insert button please help and no errors are given at all

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using DataBaseConnection;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
namespace Students
{
    public class Program
    {
        // Filling The Fields 
        private int StudentID = 0;
        private string StudentName = "";
        private  int SudentAge = 0;
        private SqlConnection Connection = new SqlConnection();

        // Properties 

        // Student ID 
        public int StudentID1
        {
            get { return StudentID; }
            set { StudentID = value; }
        }

        // Student Name 
        public string StudentName1
        {
            get { return StudentName; }
            set { StudentName = value; }
        }
        // SudentAge 


        public int SudentAge1
        {
            get { return SudentAge; }
            set { SudentAge = value; }
        }

        // Insert Method 
        public void Insert()
        {
            SqlConnection Connection = new SqlConnection(DBC.Constructor);
            string Sql = "insert into Details (StudentID,StudentName,SudentAge) Values (@StudentID1,@StudentName1,@SudentAge1)";
            SqlCommand Command = new SqlCommand(Sql, Connection);
            Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StudentID1", StudentID);
            Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StudentName1", StudentName);
            Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StudentAge1", SudentAge);


            try
            {
                Connection.Open();
                Command.ExecuteNonQuery();

                try
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Execute success");
                }

                catch
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Execute is not success");
                }

            }
            catch
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error saving Student");
            }
            finally
            {
                try
                {

                    Connection.Close();
                }
                catch
                {
                }
            }
        }
```

this is my button class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using Students;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using DataBaseConnection;
using System.Data;
public partial class SignUp : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public static string Constructor = "Data Source=FOUAD-PC;Initial Catalog=Students;Integrated Security=True";
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }


    protected void InsertButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Program X = new Program();
        X.StudentName1 = NameTxt.Text;
        X.SudentAge1 = int.Parse(AgeTxt.Text);
        X.StudentID1 = int.Parse(IDTxt.Text);

        X.Insert();

    }

}
```

Comment: Why have u given tag `c` change it to `c#`

Comment: And MySql ? It seems that you are using Sql Server.

Comment: the error have been eaten on that lines `Console.WriteLine` that have nothing to do with web pages

Comment: Is `SudentAge` the real column name or is this your error (`StudentAge` instead)? And the parameter name doesn't match also

Comment: try catch inside try catch ??

Comment: Have you tried debugging it? Insert a break point in the try-catch block if you don't need to display it in your page perhaps, you want know if an error is caught by your try-catch block code

Answer (score 1):

```
and no errors are given at all
```

I answer to that, you use the `Console.WriteLine` to show the error, or the success.

But you call this object from inside a web page that actually have no access to console, and not read that console writeline. So your errors will not been shown when you call it as it is from a web page, only when you call it from console application.

How to rewrite it.

Use a string inside your object for the errors and write there your error, eg

```
catch(Exception x)
{
   // change that 
   // Console.WriteLine("Execute is not success");
   // with 
   lastError = "Execute is not success - reason:" + x.ToString();
}
```

and `lastError` is a public string on your object, and check it after you make your calls.
You also have some "on the air" try/catch that not work at all if this is the correct code of you.

Answer (score 1):

// Insert Method

```
public int Insert(Program program)
    {
      int resutl;
        SqlConnection Connection = new SqlConnection(DBC.Constructor);
        string Sql = "insert into Details (program.StudentID,program.StudentName,program.SudentAge) Values (@StudentID1,@StudentName1,@SudentAge1)";
        SqlCommand Command = new SqlCommand(Sql, Connection);
        Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StudentID1", program.StudentID);
        Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StudentName1", program.StudentName);
        Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StudentAge1", program.SudentAge);


        try
        {
            Connection.Open();
         resutl=   Command.ExecuteNonQuery();

            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Execute success");
            }

            catch
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Execute is not success");
            }
        Return resutl;
        }
        catch
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error saving Student");
        }
        finally
        {
            try
            {

                Connection.Close();
            }
            catch
            {
            }
        }
```